# How can I collect Vec<String> from &HashSet<String>?

Tags: rust

Converting from `HashSet<String>` to `Vec<String>` is pretty straightforward:

```
let hs: HashSet<String> = HashSet::new();
let v: Vec<String> = hs.into_iter().collect();
```

What's the easiest way to do the same but from a *reference* to a HashSet?

This doesn't work:

```
let hs: HashSet<String> = HashSet::new();
let ref_to_hs: &HashSet<String> = &hs;
let v: Vec<String> = ref_to_hs.into_iter().collect();
```

It results in:

```
error[E0277]: a value of type `Vec<std::string::String>` cannot be built from an iterator over elements of type `&std::string::String`
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, I found I can do this:

```
let v: Vec<String> = ref_to_hs.clone().into_iter().collect();
```

and it seems to work.
Is there, however, a better (more efficient) way to do it?

Comment: `ref_to_hs.into_iter().cloned().collect()` will avoid cloning the `HashSet` itself, it will only duplicate the internal strings.

Comment: @SvenMarnach I just took the snippet and moved the relevant bits around, and it makes no difference, `<&HashSet>::into_iter` delegates to `HashSet::iter`.